# How to get documents by using date as the string comparison from elastic search?

Tags: c#, datetime, elasticsearch

I am calling `ElasticSearch` to get documents and then load it up in memory.
I have a below code which uses `DateRange` where it says give me documents which is greater than `currentDocumentTime`.

```
ISearchResponse<DataHolder> docManifests = await queryClient.SearchAsync<DataHolder>(search => search
    .Index("full_processVersion")
    .Type("ProcessVersion")
    .Query(query => query
        .DateRange(dateRangeQuery => dateRangeQuery
            .Field("DocumentCreatedDate")
            .GreaterThan(currentDocumentTime.Value))));
```

Now I am thinking if there is any way to modify above query so that instead of using `GreaterThan` query on `currentDocumentTime` - I can say give me all the docs which is `GreaterThan` or `LessThan` `currentDocumentTime`.

Basically idea is doing string comparison meaning give me *docs* for any *date* which doesn't match `currentDocumentTime`.

For example if `currentDocumentTime` is *Oct 10* let's say and there is some document present for Oct 09 so I should be able to get that as well.

Is this possible to do by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `term` on date type field, as well. So, your elasticsearch query is something like this:

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must_not": [
       {
         "term": {
               "DocumentCreatedDate": "Your Requested time"
             }
        }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I see. Can you provide an example on how can I use `term` in my above query code. I recently started working with Elastic Search so kinda confuse on this.

Comment: Hi, Unfurtunately I am not a C# developer. but I could generate this query considering yours and reading the tutorial. I hope it is true. your query would be something like this: ```ISearchResponse<DataHolder> docManifests = await queryClient.SearchAsync<DataHolder>(search => search
.Index("full_processVersion") 
.Type("ProcessVersion") 
.Query(query => !query
.Term(p => p.DocumentCreatedDate,currentDocumentTime.Value)));```